# Insert named range of text in worksheet using a dropdown menu in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Dropdown menu in Excel using VBA. When you select an item on the Dropdown menu, it should take a named range in the Workbook and insert it in a range below. I want to do this so I can compare various ranges.

I am unsure how to tackle this, this is what I've tried so far:

```
Function Compare()    
    Dim variable1 As String
    Dim variable2 As String

    Dim dd1 As DropDown
    Dim dd2 As DropDown

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Compare")

    Set dd1 = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("dropdown1")
    Set dd2 = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("dropdown2")
    Set r1 = ws.Range(dd1.ListFillRange)
    Set r2 = ws.Range(dd2.ListFillRange)

    Set variable1 = r1(dd1.Value)
    Set variable2 = r2(dd2.Value)

    If variable1 = "Example 1" Then        
        wb.ws.Range("h12:j58").Value = Range("ap_ks")        
    End If

End Function
```

I've managed to do it with an IF statement, but only for 1 of the items so far. Doing it for all items would make the formula very large, so instead I am trying to do it in VBA.

```
{=IFS(D8=Overview!C8;IF(AP_KS=0;"";AP_KS);0=1;)}
```

Comment: `h12:j:58` is no valid range address. Did you mean `h12:j58`? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: I tried to fix it, but unfortunately this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The following copies a selected range from one sheet (given a sequence of columns) onto a selected column in another, skipping the headers. It works with a couple activex comboboxes for selecting the columns rather than dropdowns and named range.

The column subset is partly dynamic, based on the existence of headers & some constants; updates whenever switching sheets (adding to workbook open is a good idea, and selection change is an overkill in my opinion).

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Copypasta
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Copypasta
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
' Both sheets.
Update_Combox
End Sub

' I've put the following code in a separate module for accessibility.

Const CFIRSTCOL = 6
Const CLASTCOL = -1
Const CSHEET = "Sheet1"
Const PFIRSTCOL = 1
Const PLASTCOL = -1 ' 3
Const PDEFCOL = 1 ' This is 0 indexed.
Const PSHEET = "Sheet2"

Sub Update_Combox()
' Populates the column selection lists.
Dim indstop As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim ctrlsht
Dim csht
Set csht = Sheets(CSHEET)
Set ctrlsht = Sheets(CSHEET)
ctrlsht.ComboBox1.Clear
indstop = False
i = CFIRSTCOL
While Not indstop
    If i > CLASTCOL And CLASTCOL <> -1 Then
        indstop = True
    ElseIf csht.Cells(1, i) = "" Then
        indstop = True
    Else
        ctrlsht.ComboBox1.AddItem csht.Cells(1, i)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

Set csht = Sheets(PSHEET)
ctrlsht.ComboBox2.Clear
indstop = False
i = PFIRSTCOL
While Not indstop
    If i > PLASTCOL And PLASTCOL <> -1 Then
        indstop = True
    ElseIf csht.Cells(1, i) = "" Then
        indstop = True
    Else
        ctrlsht.ComboBox2.AddItem csht.Cells(1, i)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
ctrlsht.ComboBox2.ListIndex = PDEFCOL
End Sub

Sub Copypasta()
' Copypasta selected column to another sheet.
Dim copycol As Integer
Dim pastacol As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim lastrow2 As Integer
Dim csht
Dim psht
Set csht = Sheets(CSHEET)
Set psht = Sheets(PSHEET)
If csht.ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 And csht.ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    copycol = CFIRSTCOL + csht.ComboBox1.ListIndex
    pastacol = PFIRSTCOL + csht.ComboBox2.ListIndex
    ' Need to clear the entire pasta range first.
    lastrow2 = psht.Cells(Rows.Count, pastacol).End(xlUp).Row
    if lastrow2 > 1 then
        Range(psht.Cells(2, pastacol), psht.Cells(lastrow2, pastacol)).Clear
    end if

    lastrow = csht.Cells(Rows.Count, copycol).End(xlUp).Row
    Range(psht.Cells(2, pastacol), psht.Cells(lastrow, pastacol)).Value = _
        Range(csht.Cells(2, copycol), csht.Cells(lastrow, copycol)).Value
    'psht.Activate
Else
    ' pass
End If
End Sub
```

---

Edit: Added some notes and small bugfix above. Including some shots below for reference.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTb7Q.png)

[Dropbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZmOJ.png)

[Other dropbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioSu0.png)

[Target sheet, empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLgS1.png)

[Copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CRbK.png)

[Pasta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFCck.png)

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately this does not work. Also, you are declaring constants outside any sub or function

Comment: The code was tested prior to publishing. If you could elaborate on what isn't working for you, it would go a long way towards correcting it. I've added a few notes which might not have been readily apparent before, and shots of the process to demonstrate how it should be working.

And yeah, that's how one declares globals in vba (though they have to be at the top of the module).